# Camera settings

Tags: nikon, camera-settings, outdoor, indoor

I can’t seem to get my camera settings right, can someone list the right settings for indoor pictures. Trying to take pictures of my dog but it’s been raining. Also list good outdoor settings as well, so maybe like tell me what’s the best ISO, shutter speed, exc. thank you.

Comment: There aren't really "best settings" — if there were, the camera would just always use them. You need to adapt to the environment. To understand that, please see [this question](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/72388/what-is-the-relationship-between-iso-aperture-and-shutter-speed), as it explains ISO, shutter speed, and aperture, and why you might want to use different settings in different situations.

Comment: One approach might be to use the "auto" mode and see what settings it picks.

Comment: Also, if you have a specific example, we could maybe help with what went wrong in that case.

Comment: Have you tried (A)uto or (P)rogrammed Exposure?

Comment: @xiota I have tried Programmed and it still doesn’t take good pictures. I’ll try auto.

Comment: @mattdm I will try to post a picture later maybe

Comment: We can definitely help you figure out why Program mode isn't doing what you want, and help you know exactly what to do in response. The fact that it *isn't* getting good pictures is exactly why we can't just tell you what settings to use. I'm looking forward to seeing your examples.

Comment: @mattdm I can’t seem to figure out how to include a example picture :/

Comment: @mattdm I’ll just explain what it’s doing, whenever I take a picture indoors of my dog that is not moving btw comes out blurry and over exposed. The camera seems slow, I notice when it takes a picture slow it does the over exposed blurry thing, I did get some good pictures. It’s on ISO 1600

Answer (score 4):

Good indoor settings: Auto.

Good outdoor settings: Auto.

What camera do you have?

Read your camera manual, and maybe start to research here about exposure (see the links posted by mattdm in the comments). You can experiment with exposure settings then, but until that point, there's nothing wrong with using Auto.

Comment: I rented a camera from my photography teacher, it’s a small nickon camera with a macro lens on it.