# Why isn't shutter priority mode automatically adjusting my aperture on my Nikon Coolpix P520?

Tags: shutter-priority

I've tried different ISO settings as well as auto ISO, but whatever the ISO, when I'm in shutter priority mode, the camera isn't automatically adjusting the aperture as I change shutter speed. I'm just ending up with very dark pictures. Is this a problem with the camera or am I missing something? Help!

Comment: Did you read the manual about it?

Comment: What is recorded in the EXIF info of the pictures? What ISO, what aperture, and what shutter speed? What were the lighting conditions where you took the photos?

Comment: Can you post an example image? Maybe you have exposure compensation dialed way down by mistake? Does the camera have any minimums or maximums that it's not allowed to go past (say, 1600ISO) - and you're simply in too dark a scene for the current settings?

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like you might be selecting a shutter value that is too short (too "fast") for the amount of light in the scene you are photographing, even when the lens is opened to its maximum aperture and the camera is set to its highest ISO value.

Answer (score 2):

[Page 70 of the manual states](https://cdn-10.nikon-cdn.com/pdf/manuals/coolpix/P520RM_EN.pdf#page=70):

> **When the subject is too dark or too bright, it may not be possible to obtain the appropriate exposure.** In such cases, the shutter speed indicator or aperture value indicator flashes when the shutter-release button is pressed halfway (except when the `M` mode is used). **Change the shutter speed setting or aperture value [or ISO value].**

<sup>Emphasis mine, words in brackets are condensed information from the rest of the original paragraph.</sup>

---

### Technical explanation:

**For better explanations, please see ["What is the relationship between ISO, aperture, and shutter speed?"](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/72388/what-is-the-relationship-between-iso-aperture-and-shutter-speed)**

There are three values that have influence on the exposure: ISO, shutter speed and aperture. You chose to set ISO and shutter speed, which leaves the aperture to the camera's CPU.

The aperture is limited by the lens's design - your camera has a variable maximum aperture of [`f/3-5.9` (and a maximum ISO of 6400)](https://cdn-10.nikon-cdn.com/pdf/manuals/coolpix/P520RM_EN.pdf#page=235).

Think, for example, of the following situation:

The scene is very cloudy and therefore, you would need something like `ISO 400 @ 1/100s @ f/4`. You, however, have decided to use `ISO 100 @ 1/200s` - ISO alone would require 2 full stops, and the shorter shutter speed is 1 additional stop, so your aperture would need to be opened by 3 full stops, thus requiring `f/1.4` instead of `f/4`.

Your camera, however, can only deliver `f/3`, resulting in a picture about 2 full stops too dark.

<sub>God - I hope that these calculations are correct. This always gives me a headache...</sub>