# Which settings are needed in this situation in order to have equivalent exposure?

Tags: exposure, lighting, camera-settings

Two Wedding Videographers will cover a wedding ceremony. Both use a Canon Eos 80D DSLR camera with different lenses.

The first videographer used a Canon EF 50mm F / 1.8 lens with aperture settings (ISO: 400, F: 2.8, and SS 1/250)

The second videographer used a Canon EF 18 - 55 kit lens.

How is a second videographer change the settings so that they both get the same Normal lighting with the first Videographer if the ISO remains the same at 400 ?

Comment: Could you edit your question to explain what "Normal lighting" is? Do you mean that the exposure between videographers should be the same?

Comment: yes i mean that.

Comment: As you mention video will be better to ask in https://video.stackexchange.com

Comment: Is this a homework question?

Comment: Thanks for the clarifying edit. Please [take the tour](https://photo.stackexchange.com/tour) to understand that it is expected that for every question you do some research yourself. What previous questions did you look into to understand how exposure works for example?

Comment: @xiota  Train A will get to the station 14 minutes before train B.

Comment: [What is the relationship between ISO, aperture, and shutter speed?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/q/72388/75526), [What is the “exposure triangle”?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/q/6598/75526)

Comment: This is not off-topic by reason of video. That VtC reason text is: "This his question is about video **in a context that is not likely to be relevant to still photography.**" This **clearly** has a context that is relevant to still photography (i.e., equivalent exposure). Hell, the question isn't even _unambiguously_ about video, only that videographers were using DSLRs to capture something that _may_ or _may not_ be photos or videos.

Answer (score 1):

The second photographer is using an 18-55mm kit lens. At 50mm all of Canon's 18-55mm kit lenses have a maximum aperture of f/5.6.

If one is constrained by using ISO 400 and 50mm in order to match the other camera, then the only variable left is exposure duration, otherwise known colloquially as "shutter speed".

Since f/5.6 is two stops slower than f/2.8 used by the other photographer, the exposure time must be two stops longer.

Two stops longer than 1/250 is 1/60.

So the second photographer must use 1/60 with ISO 400 and f/5.6 to get the same exposure values as the first photographer using 1/250 with ISO 400 and f/2.8.

This presents another issue, however. Assuming both cameras are shooting video at the same frame rate, the footage at 1/250 will look "choppy" compared to the footage shot at 1/60.

Answer (score 0):

Equivalent exposures are:

ISO 400 f/2.8 1/250 second

ISO 400 f/4 1/125

ISO 400 f/5.6 1/60

ISO 400 f/8  1/30

ISO 200 f/4 1/60

ISO 200 f/5.6 1/30

Stopping down one stop of aperture is compensated by one stop slower shutter speed,
OR by one stop smaller ISO.

Comment: If we talk about video you can't change so sample shutter speed. IMHO the ISO is the only variable you can play with

Comment: Of course you can.  You can make shutter speed faster in any degree that still exposes satisfactorily. Those lesser exposed images are still shown at 30 per second.  You just cannot make shutter speed slower than 1/30 second (or 24 per second if provided).

Comment: Wayne, you can, but this will change the movie :) https://youtu.be/qZHXTZvQdzI?t=187

Comment: Shutter speed may change the perceived smoothness of any motion, but if equivalent, it does not change the "lighting" if assumed the question means exposure.

Comment: But it mention video, so its not only exposure :)

Comment: @RomeoNinov You are right in that for video work, a 180° shutter angle rule should be used, but the OP anyway used 1/250, so changing SS is porbably not a problem...

Comment: You're right, thank you. Was going too fast, I should have checked it.  I have corrected the two ISO 200 values.