# What is the major difference between aperture and shutter?

Tags: aperture, camera-settings, shutter-speed, shutter, camera-basics

There is some thing which I get from google is: Aperture controls sharpness and focus of photo and also how much light enter in camera. Shutter is how much time shutter open and get light into light sensor.

#### My Question

The Both Shutter and Aperture gets light into camera then what is difference between them?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the relationship between ISO, aperture, and shutter speed?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/72388/what-is-the-relationship-between-iso-aperture-and-shutter-speed)

Comment: @MrUpsidown NO Read my question again ...

Comment: @Hamza Please explain _why_ that doesn't answer your question, we're not mind-readers. The answers there go into great detail as to what effect shutter speed and aperture have on a picture, what information is still missing in your view?

Comment: What research/reading have you done? All I can see is one (out of context) quotation snatched from a quick web search it seems. Do you know how the iris in a lens works?

Comment: @osullic i just want to know how camera works . i am not photographer !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's the combination of aperture and shutter (a.k.a. "speed") that determines how much light is received by the sensor (like a faucet: how much water you get is controlled by how much you open the faucet (aperture) and how long you keep it open (speed)). But it's not just how much light you receive, so different combinations have their specific uses.

Aperture controls focus blur (a.k.a "depth of field" or DoF), shutter controls motion blur, so it depends which one you want to reduce, or which one you want to take advantage off.

For instance, in an air show, you want to keep some motion blur when shooting propeller planes to avoid freezing the propeller (otherwise it looks like the engine is stopped) so you use speeds around 1/250s. No such problem with jets that in addition are somewhat faster, so you use much higher speeds (1/1000s or more) if there is enough light.

In many other cases (portrait, architecture, macro photography) you want to control DoF, so your main choice is aperture, and speed is whatever is fast enough to keep motion blur in control.

These two are why cameras have "Aperture priority" and "Shutter priority" modes. You set one of the two and the camera adjusts the other for proper exposure.

Comment: ok it means both control how much light enter in camera ? but they have different characteristics   !??

Comment: Yes... Besides exposure, they have a different effect on the final  result. A picture taken at f/2.8, 1/1000s and one taken at f/16, 1/30s will have the same exposure, but the first will have focus blur (or "shallow DoF") and the second motion blur.

Answer (score -1):

Ok, I'll try to expand on the water analogy.

Imagine the lens as a large hose with a nozzle on the end. The aperture is how wide the nozzle is opened the speed is how long it is opened, and the amount of water that gets through is the light. And you are spraying playing kids with the hose.

Now imagine the nozzle (aperture) is opened very little to where it is just spraying drops in a mist. Very little water is getting out so the kids can run back and forth many times before getting soaked (the camera records them moving because it takes a long time to get enough light).

Now, instead imagine the nozzle (aperture) is wide open and spraying a large heavy stream of water. Because so much water is getting out the moment a kid gets hit with the stream they are soaked (the camera records less motion because it gets enough light very quickly).

In reality, the amount of light that goes through in a given time (stream vs mist) is also dependent on the light density from the scene being photographed (how bright it is)... I.e. the water pressure entering the hose.